# Canvas doesn't draw Images correctly on first draw

Tags: html5-canvas

I have been experiencing bizarre behavior with the HTML5 Canvas in Chrome. As demonstrated in the example below, the images are not rendering correctly until the window is resized. *All of the variables and properties have the exact same values both initially and on resize.* Why does this happen?

Of course if the image hasn't loaded yet, the background won't display at all. You may need to refresh a few times.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#test-canvas');
    var backgroundImage = new Image(100, 100);

    backgroundImage.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/100';

    var dimensions = [];
    var center = [];
    var viewBox = [];

    function paint() {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      dimensions = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
      center = [dimensions[0] / 2, dimensions[1] / 2];
      viewBox = [
        -center[0], -center[1],
        center[0], center[1],
      ];

      ctx.translate(center[0], center[1]);

      paintBackground(ctx);
    }

    function paintBackground(ctx) {
      ctx.save();

      var size = [100, 100]

      var box = [
        Math.floor(viewBox[0] / size[0]) * size[0],
        Math.floor(viewBox[1] / size[1]) * size[1],
        Math.ceil(viewBox[2] / size[0]) * size[0],
        Math.ceil(viewBox[3] / size[1]) * size[1],
      ];

      for (let x = box[0]; x < box[2]; x += size[0]) {
        for (let y = box[1]; y < box[3]; y += size[1]) {
          ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, size[0], size[1]);
        }
      }

      ctx.restore();
    }

    function resize() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        paint();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    resize();

    setTimeout(paint, 200); 

</script>
</html>
```

The images should be covering the entire canvas...

[image]

But initially they only cover the lower right quadrant...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was translating every time I painted. I realized I needed to put a call to `save` and `restore` within my `paint` method. This solved my problem.

```
function paint() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.save() // <--- here!

  dimensions = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
  center = [dimensions[0] / 2, dimensions[1] / 2];
  viewBox = [
    -center[0], -center[1],
    center[0], center[1],
  ];

  ctx.translate(center[0], center[1]);

  paintBackground(ctx);

  ctx.restore() // <--- and here!
}
```